# Use Sylvestor's Criterion to classify the critical point?

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I am asked to find and classify the critical point of $g(x,y,z) = xy-x+2z-x^2-y^2-z^2$

I have calculated the derivative and found that the critical point is at $(-\frac23, -\frac13, 1)$

I have found the Hessian matrix = 
$$
\left[\matrix{-2 & 1 & 0\\1 &-2 & 0\\0 &0 &-2}\right]
$$

But when I calculate the leading principle minors, I get $-2$, $3$ and $-6$. Wolframalpha tells me that this point is a maximum, so I should be getting all negative values to make the matrix negative definite.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: ummmm... all negative ***eigenvalues***. The principal minors should alternate to get negative definite. Do the same exercise for $-x^2 - y^2 - z^2.$ The Hessian is $-2I.$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Negative-definite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done everything right except for the conclusion. According to Sylvester, a matrix is positive-definite iff all principal minors are positive, but it **does not mean** that for negative-definite all are negative. Easy exercise: take a negative-definite $A$, then $(-A)$ is positive-definite. Apply Sylvester to $(-A)$ and use the fact that $\det(-M)=(-1)^n\det(M)$ for $n\times n$ matrix $M$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Negative-definite

Comment: @WillJagy To do it once yourself is the best for understanding. It is VERY typical mistake, I have some students in my class almost every year who think the minors should be all negative.

Comment: Oh, sure. I asked the OP to do $-x^2 - y^2 - z^2$ where the Hessian is very clear, and the principal minors. I don't have good luck getting OP's to actually do anything.